# Edit read-only XML file in Pi

Tags: pi-3, readwrite

I want to edit one XML file in Pi 3.
I used the command `vi` to edit it, but at the end I am not able to save it, it gives me an error

> E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)

Comment: I'm not really sure how you expect us to answer this question... What file? What are its permissions? Where in the directory structure is it?

Comment: what is the output of ls -la run from the directory containing the file in question?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found the solution

```
sudo leafpad /location
```